# Removing POC(Proof of concept server) from the server farm

Tags: 2007

I am on MOSS, the environments i have are Production then Test/dev/QA and then Test/dev/qa/poc, i dont know why there are so many environments but i never use the POC environments now upper authorities are asking me if we are not using the POC machine lets decomission this single machine out of the Test/dev/QA/Poc env.I joined this company recently so i dont know what was going on and why did they even have this on first place.My question is if i say yes to decomisson it would there be any aftereffects or would there be any downtime in my production environment.

I dont see any connection of that POC machine with my production environment.Is there any way to check if this is connected or are there any services running which after decommisoning might effect the production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of your POC server, it's hard to say. Generally speaking, though, removing a server from your farm is as easy as uninstalling SharePoint from the server itself (in fact, if you try to remove the server from SharePoint first, it will recommend that you do this instead). If you've got a whole different standalone server farm, decommissioning it ought to have no effect, period, as SharePoint is built with a mind towards keeping server farms as separate and distinct as possible.

Comment: Would like to add some things to check for:

Are there any services that are running on this server that aren't on other servers?  May need a migration strategy.

Watch for other applications (not necessarily SharePoint) as well.  POC Servers have a way of getting other applications on them in addition to SharePoint in my experience.

Comment: MiKe/John - Thank you for looking into this..finally after shooting couple of emails to the big shots they found one guys who apparently knew something about this POC server and he said that the time tracking application team has used this site as a document repository and he says lets retain this server until we decommission this SharePoint farm (either as a results of a SharePoint upgrade or a migration to a different platform)..Well ia m glad i am off the hook to worry about this Server.Thank you guys once again for your efforts.